# Filter Creditmemmos with Date is throwing error in admin

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, exception

While In admin and filter the creditmemos with specific dates it throwing exception.

```
UI component could not be rendered because of system exception , errorcode: "23000"
```

Tried clearing cache, and deployed the static content again, but still the issue is there,

Note: there is not any customization done on this GRID, it is default magento running!

Is there any workaround to fix this issue?

Error in Exception log is:

```
main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_creditmemo_grid` AS `main_table`
LEFT JOIN `sales_order` AS `bss_sales` ON main_table.order_id = bss_sales.entity_id WHERE  (((`created_at` >= '2022-05-05 00:00:00'))) AND (((`created_at` <= '2022-06-01 23:59:59'))) {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_creditmemo_grid` AS `main_table`
LEFT JOIN `sales_order` AS `bss_sales` ON main_table.order_id = bss_sales.entity_id WHERE  (((`created_at` >= '2022-05-05 00:00:00'))) AND (((`created_at` <= '2022-06-01 23:59:59'))) at /vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:110, PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous at /vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:91)"} []
```

thanks!

Comment: Check your system.log and exception.log, also check response under network on your browser against your request.

Comment: Yes this is the response in Network:
UI component could not be rendered because of system exception , errorcode: "23000"

Comment: Then check the log files, you will get something there.

Comment: Search for **bss_sales** in your code. There must have any module adding some column or maybe rewriting some functionality there

Comment: @SukumarGorai Yes I have added  the error and updated the question please check!

Comment: Check your Bss modules there must be something.